# ASp.Net Chart with string values on X and Y axis

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, charts

I have using asp.net chart in my application. Here, I would like to display StackedBar chart with the value of **x-axis** and **y-axis**. Note that here, value on both axis would be string. Value may be like as below:

```
Container-No.               Destination
    X001                      City-X
    X002                      City-S
    X003                      City-R
```

Here, Container No display on Y-axis and Destination on X-axis, and graph would be stackedBar.

Have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
string[] yValues = { "X001","X002","X003" };
string[] xValues = { "City-X","City-S","City-R"};
Chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
```

Comment: Hi Rohit, 
got error from code , error like as below:
"Y values cannot be data bound to the string object.
Parameter name: yValues "
Please, check above error and please, post answer after proper checking or give special instruction if have for configuration required for that.